# Django models as optgroup choices

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get my installed models as opt group choices.

I have to do it in my model, not form.

so far I tried.

```
def get_installed_model_choices():
    returnval = []
    for app in settings.SYSTEM_INSTALLED_APPS:
        app_config = apps.get_app_config(app)
        app_models = app_config.get_models()
        model_choices = []
        for model in app_models:
            model_choices.append([model._meta.model_name, model._meta.verbose_name])
        returnval.append([app_config.verbose_name, model_choices])
    print returnval
    return returnval
```

And in my model field.

```
model = custom_model_fields.PanNoneBlankCharField(choices = get_installed_model_choices(),verbose_name=_('model'),
                                                  max_length=20)
```

I get this error.

```
"Models for app '%s' haven't been imported yet." % self.label)
```

---

Second approach:
This is comething I saw on the internet,

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PanUserModelPermissions, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._meta.get_field('model')._choices = \
        lazy(get_installed_model_choices, list)()
```

This didnt work either, had no affect

I dont want choices to be static, is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to choice from your models,you can use content_type as:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 verbose_name=u'content_type ')
```

more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

Comment: I thought of that, but I dont want a foreignkey. Thanks.